# Mathematically explain web servers uptime

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance

I want to mathematicaly explain a set of servers based on their uptime. Some computers they are constantly running and some of them they go off and on over time which their off time and on time can be different. So how can I mathematically show that:

- Some servers are more frequently off (or on)
- Some servers their uptime is longer than offtime, or vice versa.

How can I explain/show this information mathematically?